# Find best power of data to give straight line

Tags: fitting

I have data which follows a power law - I'm just not sure which one.

It could be modelled with something like:

```
power = RandomInteger[{1, 10}];

data = Table[x^(power), {x, 20}];

ListPlot[data]
```

[image]

Now, I want to find the power which might best give me a straight line. This, of course, would be the inverse of power.

i.e.

```
ListPlot[data^(1/power)]
```

[image]

But, how would I do this with empirical data. I cannot get `FindFit` to do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Log log transform:

```
power = RandomInteger[{1, 10}];
data = Table[{x, x^(power)}, {x, 20}];
dt = {Log@#1, Log@#2} & @@@ data;
lm = LinearModelFit[dt, {x}, x]
lm["BestFitParameters"][[2]]
power
Plot[Exp[lm[Log[x]]], {x, 1, 20}, Epilog -> Point[data], 
 PlotLabel -> Exp[lm[Log[x]]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was being stupid.

```
FindFit[data, x^y, y, x]
```

Gives you the right answer, then just take the inverse of that. Silly me. Its obvious.

Comment: You could also take logs...

Comment: It's not always obvious and depends on the "real" data.  Consider estimating the power as a parameter with a Box-Cox transformation.  And note that "straightening out" the relationship some times messes with the assumption of constant variance about the line.